# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?

Tags: debian, sudo, display, gtk

I'm having this problem on my Debian box (Buster). Whenever I run the command

```
sudo ./FreeFileSync
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key10:24:17: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

So I checked the DISPLAY environment variable as follows:

```
rekotc@QSTACKER:~/FreeFileSync$ env | grep DISPLAY
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
DISPLAY=:0
```

It seems correctly set up. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running X11 or Wayland?  How to find out: `ps aux | grep bin/X | grep -v grep` and see whether you can find X. Write that line here if you find it.

Comment: @Ned64 this?  1:58 /usr/bin/Xwayland :0

Comment: @mosvy sorry but i don't understand what you mean when you say "from a place where you CAN connect to the display". If i run the command `xhost SI:localuser:root` logged as an unprivileged user i get `xhost:  unable to open display ""`

Comment: Well, then go RTFM until you understand everything to the point where you can figure it out yourself. I don't believe that that X server is running in some ethereal place, without any terminal emulator, DE with "run command" applet, etc, and you're not even able to figure out what user it's running as.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately i don't have the time to get into deeper details right now. I've logged in using Gnome on Xorg, now the command i've always used works again

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged into a machine using the user `john` then only that user has the right to draw something on the screen, read keyboard and mouse movements etc. Even the user `root` may not do so (without some work).

Any user who also needs to log in needs to be able to present a secret key.  Under X11 that can be found in some location like a file in `/run`.  Here is an example:

```
john@pc:  ps aux | grep bin/X | grep -v grep
root     1125  5.0  0.5 1982242 145420 tty7   Rsl+ Mar26  96:33 /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /run/folder/{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789a} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt7
```

Here you can see that the X server is started with the `-auth` parameter as a file, in this case `/run/folder/{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789a}` (yes, that is a file).

In the case of Wayland it can look like this:

```
john@pc:  ps aux | grep /Xorg | grep -v grep
john     2490  2.8  0.7 628618 86908 tty2     Sl+  21:26   0:03 /usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -nolisten tcp -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

Here you can see that the file name is `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`.

So, if `root` wants to start a program with graphical interface they need to have that file, and it will be searched in their `~/.Xauthority` file.

So, prepare by copying the file:

```
john@pc:  sudo cat /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority > /root/.Xauthority
```

then execute the command:

```
john@pc:  sudo ./FreeFileSync
```

That works for me.

Comment: @mosvy When Xwayland is running I can run an X program with correct `~/.Xauthority`. The program does seem to be using X, not Wayland (see OP's erroe message).

Comment: @mosvy My local root user only needs to access one display server.

Comment: My output for `ps aux | grep bin/X | grep -v grep` is `rekotc    1640  1.8  0.7 607232 48352 tty2     Sl+  09:48   2:14 /usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6` and my output for `ps aux | grep /Xorg | grep -v grep` is empty...

Comment: I could fix my xauth file using this guide, thank you. I'm however not getting it, root couldn't connect because cookie was invalid, but X process was owned by root user! Is it supposed to work this way?

Comment: @AlirezaMohamadi Yes, that would be expected. Basically, X allows access (by its API) to anyone who can quote a "magic number" (think password). `root` may do anything, so they can read and copy that password from the correct file. However, without it X will give an error even to them.